# Loading a UIViewController Dynamically with MvvmCross

Tags: uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, segue, mvvmcross

I'm trying to load a ViewModel-bound ViewController from a XIB or storyboard (using MvvmCross 5.0.6). The logic is of my app is such that this view controller doesn't fall into the standard root/child navigation pattern and I need to be able to instantiate it dynamically.

Without MvvmCross, I could easily use segues for this in Xamarin.iOS, but MvvmCross doesn't seem to work with segues (unless I'm misunderstanding something).

**How do I instantiate the view controller so that it's bound to its view model and I can pass it to method like UIViewController.AddChildViewController()?**

I've tried the following, but it results in a NullReferenceException (at MvxViewModelLoader.LoadViewModel(MvxViewModelRequest request, IMvxBundle savedState)):

```
var vmRequest = new MvxViewModelRequest(typeof(MyVcViewModel));
var myVc = (segue.DestinationViewController as MvxViewController).CreateViewControllerFor<MyVcViewModel>(vmRequest) as MyVc;

this.AddChildViewController(myVc);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you bound the `MyVcViewModel` to your `MyVc`? If the `MyVc` can be used as a root/child navigation pattern successfully, try this to show it as a content (maybe you can put this in `ViewDidLoad()` event):

```
var vmRequest = MvxViewModelRequest.GetDefaultRequest(typeof(MyVcViewModel));

var viewController = new MvxViewController();
var myView = viewController.CreateViewControllerFor<MyVcViewModel>(vmRequest) as MyVc;
myView.View.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, 200, 200);


AddChildViewController(myView);
View.AddSubview(myView.View);
```

Comment: Thank you, @LandLu-MSFT. This worked perfectly. It's frustrating that this isn't mentioned anywhere in the documentation.